# Is it possible to set opening certain apps such as Safari, iWork, MS Office in the full Window mode by default like Mail App (macOS Catalina)?

Tags: safari, applications, catalina, window-manager, iwork

The only App I can set opening in the full window is Apple's Mail App - it can be set in the App setting. I suppose other application could be set via terminal commands, but I'm not that handy with terminal commands to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can open any app in full window

Use keyboard shortcut

**Command + Control + F**

Same to exit full window as well

Comment: Sure, but I want the App to open in the full window by default without using any commands.